# splitting a paragraph based on space and remove the extra spaces

Tags: python

I have a paragraph like where I need to split every word by spaces.

Data :

```
BigMart has collected 2013 sales data for 1559 products  across 10 stores in different cities. The aim is to build a predictive model and find out the sales of each product at a store.

Python    
java     
data scientist
```

output :

```
bigmart
has
collected
2013
sales
data
for
1559
products


across
10
stores
in
different
cities.
the
aim
is
to
build
a
predictive
```

There is a lot of space between the products and across. Is there a way to remove this ?

Comment: How are you getting that output?

Comment: Please post what you've tried. This currently reads as "please do the coding for me" - that's not what SO is about.

Comment: I used  `for word in mystring.split("  "):`which has given me that output.

Answer (score 3):

string.split() method without an argument splits on whitespace:

```
myText = "BigMart has collected"
splitText = myText.split()
print(splitText)
```

Output:

```
['BigMart', 'has', 'collected']
```

You can read more about split method on : https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '''BigMart has collected 2013 sales data for 1559 products  across 10 stores in 
      different cities. The aim is to build a predictive model and find out the sales 
      of each product at a store.

      Python    
      java     
      data scientist'''

for i in s.split():print(i)

#Output
BigMart
has
collected
2013
sales
data
for
1559
products
across
10
stores
in
different
cities.
The
aim
is
to
build
a
predictive
.
.
```

if you want the result into a list

```
print(s.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the extra spaces, you can filter out items that aren't 'truthy':

```
test = "BigMart has collected 2013 sales data for 1559 products  across 10 stores in different cities. The aim is to build a predictive model and find out the sales of each product at a store."

words = [word for word in test.split(' ') if word]

for word in words:
  print(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `split()` method you will get every individual word as separated string value in a list. You will get the punctuation also (so the last value will be "store.")
If you want to split on space, do split(" ") but then you will get a list containing a lot of spaces.